# Speeding up TraMineR commands

Tags: r, performance, traminer

I have data structured in this format ([longer, but still abbreviated, dataset can be found here](http://pastebin.com/VqgaLWqZ)):

```
pull_req_id,user,action,created_at
1679,NiGhTTraX,opened,1380104504
1678,akaariai,opened,1380044613
1678,akaariai,opened,1380044618
...
```

Having the following libraries loaded:

```
library(TraMineR)
library(sqldf)
```

I load it using this function (which is quick):

```
read_seqdata <- function(data, startdate, stopdate){
  data <- read.table(data, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
  data <- subset(data, select = c("pull_req_id", "action", "created_at"))
  colnames(data) <- c("id", "event", "time")
  data <- sqldf(paste0("SELECT * FROM data WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time,
'unixepoch', 'localtime') >= '",startdate,"' AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time,
'unixepoch', 'localtime') <= '",stopdate,"'"))
  data$end <- data$time
  data <- data[with(data, order(time)), ]
  data$time <- match(data$time, unique(data$time))
  data$end <- match(data$end, unique(data$end))
  (data)
}

project_sequences <- read_seqdata("/Users/name/github/local/data/event-data.txt",
'2012-01-01', '2012-06-30')
```

And then I run this function to calculate sequence lengths (extremely slow):

```
sequence_length <- function(data){
  slmax <- max(data$time)
  sequences.sts <- seqformat(data, from="SPELL", to="DSS", begin="time",
end="end", id="id", status="event", limit=slmax)
  sequences.sts <- seqdef(sequences.sts, right = "DEL", left = "DEL",
gaps = "DEL")
  sequences.length <- seqlength(sequences.sts)
  (sequences.length)
}

project_length <- sequence_length(project_sequences)
```

However, this is painstakingly slow. Any advice on how I may refactor the code to speed it up?

Some of the timestamps are thousands of steps apart, but each sequence is just a few steps long. Could the large distances between timestamps of different sequences contribute to the long computing times (20+ hours on a University supercomputer)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the timestamps that were created by the `read_seqdata` function above, while shorter than the original seconds-since-the-epoch format, still generated timestamps that differed by as much as 50'000 units. Apparently this slows `TraMineR` down significantly. My solution was to create a new function for reading the data without timestamps:

```
read_seqdata_notime <- function(data, startdate, stopdate){
  data <- read.table(data, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
  data <- subset(data, select = c("pull_req_id", "action", "created_at"))
  colnames(data) <- c("id", "event", "time")
  data <- sqldf(paste0("SELECT * FROM data WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time,
'unixepoch', 'localtime') >= '",startdate,"' AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time,
'unixepoch', 'localtime') <= '",stopdate,"'"))
  data.split <- split(data$event, data$id)
  list.to.df <- function(arg.list) {
    max.len  <- max(sapply(arg.list, length))
    arg.list <- lapply(arg.list, `length<-`, max.len)
    as.data.frame(arg.list)
  }
  data <- list.to.df(data.split)
  data <- t(data)
  (data)  
}
```

This speeds up the computation of subsequent `TraMineR` commands substantially, but restricts the analysis of sequences to measures which are strictly about activity type or ordering, and does not consider duration (i.e. length, entropy, number of subsequences, and dissimilarity are all still OK to use).

For example, the function for storing sequence length in a variable then becomes:

```
sequence_length <- function(data){
  sequences.sts <- seqdef(data, left = "DEL", gaps = "DEL", right = "DEL")
  sequences.length <- seqlength(sequences.sts)
  (sequences.length)
}
```